# What is difference between axios and fetch in react native?

Tags: react-native, axios

I m new in a react native so please can you explain more about in this question?

Comment: https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/fetch-vs-axios-js-for-making-http-requests-2b261cdd3af5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall they are very similar the only difference is that axios is alittle bit more developed. Some benefits of axios:

```
Transformers: allow performing transforms on data before request is made or after response is received
Interceptors: allow you to alter the request or response entirely (headers as well). also perform async operations before request is made or before Promise settles
Built-in XSRF protection
```

for more info you can check this discussion https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/314